# addClass(); jQuery Function Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, addclass

I have a script that picks a random background image for the `body` element of my document from a directory called `bg-images`. If the chosen background image has "_dark" in the image file name, I would like to add a special class to the body element.

Here is the jQuery I'm using. It works great in Chrome & Safari, but does nothing in Firefox:

```
    var backgroundImage = $('body').css('background');
    var isitdark = "_dark";

    if (backgroundImage.indexOf( isitdark ) != -1 ) {
        $('body').addClass("dark");
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass("dark");
    }
```

How come this doesn't do anything in Firefox? Is there a better way of writing it?

I've tried adding `"type=text/javascript"` to all my script tags but that doesn't seem to help and the rest of the jQuery on my site works correctly in all browsers.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but try using triple equality(`!==`) when comparing the result from indexOf. These kinds of things are prone to cause strange behaviour. You should always use `===` in any case.

Comment: @HugoT the `.indexOf()` method always returns a numeric result, so `!==` won't make a difference here.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah you are right, but in any case triple equality should always be used.

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log()` to show what that "backgroundImage" variable actually contains?

Comment: It might be that the background property is not being set correctly or firefox is rewriting your css properties. Maybe they move it to the property 'background-image'

Comment: That is what Firefox logs: "TypeError: $(...).css is not a function"

Comment: @HugoT: *"in any case triple equality should always be used"* Nonsense. As long as you know what you're doing, use whatever works best.

Comment: You will have to see what the value of `backgroundImage` actually is here to see why it isn't working.  Nothing else we can do without that info. This is standard debugging.

Comment: *"I've tried adding "type=text/javascript" to all my script tags but that doesn't seem to help"* Correct. The default is and always has been JavaScript.

Comment: @christophe: *"That is what Firefox logs: "TypeError: $(...).css is not a function""* Where did you get that? It makes no sense. jQuery's `$` function **always** returns a jQuery object. It may be a zero-element set, but it has the jQuery functions on it.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy and @jfriend00. I used `console.log()` and this helped a lot.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when u put $('body').css('background') in the FF console!

Comment: @christophe: If you don't have jQuery loaded on that page (or you used `noConflict`), sure. The OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not getting the background image with `$('body').css('background');` Use `.css('background-image')`

```
var backgroundImage = $('body').css('background-image');
```

It's not necessary because the string _dark will or will not be there but if you want to you can remove the `url()` or `url("")`

```
var backgroundImage = /url\(\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\1\s*\)/g.exec($('body').css('background-image'))[2];
```

Works fine in FF

http://jsfiddle.net/mNX3A/

Comment: Just using `background-image` instead of `background` wasn't enough for some reason, I had to strip the quotes. Does anyone have an explanation for why I needed to strip the quotes for Firefox but not other browsers?

Answer (score 4):

[`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background) is a shorthand property. Shorthand properties are [not guaranteed to be retrieved correctly with `css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., `margin`, `background`, `border`), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.

If you specifically want to get `background-image`, get [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image):

```
var backgroundImage = $('body').css('background-image');
```

Comment: But the compound property should still have the filename in it so this doesn't explain why their original script wouldn't work.

Comment: @jfriend00: jQuery doesn't guarantee that shorthand properties work correctly on retrieval, it's browser-specific.